# Take element from Resources more than once in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources

I have some elements of type `Path` in XAML UserControl resources, when I try to use some element more than once (for example in two different `StackPanel`s) I get an InvalidOperationException.

What's the problem? Why resource element identifies as real component on my control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only `Freezable` objects that are frozen can be used more than once in the same visual tree.  `Path` objects are not `Freezable` objects but `FrameworkElement` objects, hence the error.  You can try using the `x:Shared="False"` attribute on the `Path` resource to create a new copy each time the resource is accessed to prevent the exception.

Comment: Yes! Thakns a lot, that was the problem.